# How to retrieve child value with pysolr

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

Good day,

First i am quite unfamiliar with solr.

I am using solr 6.6.6, python 3.7 and pysolr (the latest version).

I have a many documents with the following format:

```py
pysolr.add({
  'first_name': 'Jane',
  'last_name': 'Doe',
  'contact': {
    'phone_number': '0678901122',
    'address': 'near the fire place'
  }
})
```

I read some documentation on [yonik.com](http://yonik.com/solr/query-syntax/), [medium](https://medium.com/@pablocastelnovo/nesting-documents-in-apache-solr-12ef44ea2901) and [lucidwork](https://lucidworks.com/2009/03/31/nested-queries-in-solr/) to understand how to make a query to solr.

I have already tried the following :

```py
pysolr.search('contact.phone_number:06')
```

Obviously, this was bad and gave me the error : `[Reason: undefined field contact.zip_code]`

In the above exemple, i would like to understand how to retrieve a value from sub-element contact.

Comment: You can attach the links of yonik.com and medium where you gathered information. That will help others to follow and solve your issue.

Comment: Start by retrieving the documents that have been indexed by querying for `*:*` in the Solr web interface. I'm not familiar with how pysolr indexes child documents, if at all.